# What is the maximum of $\operatorname{Tr}(EUAU^\dagger)$ when $U$ is unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, unitary-matrices, tensor-decomposition

Given matrices $E$ and $A$, is there a good way to obtain the maximizing unitary $U$ for the objective function $\operatorname{Tr}(EUAU^*)$? (I know that the maximizer of $\operatorname{Tr}(EU)$ is given by the polar decomposition of $E$.)

Comment: Where does this objective function come from?

Comment: It comes from a physics problem.